# Is there any way to make call from php to mobile application

Tags: php, android, ios, jquery-mobile

I have image in database which i want to fetch on mobile app. I can do it with sending full URL on server (ie. `www.xyz.com/img/abc.jpg` ). but my app also work offline that time its not possible to get this images. so i need to download that images on mobile devices. so when ever any change in image on server that time i want to make call to application for new image download.

Is it good practice to store image in base64 when sending to mobile application ?

Comment: try  [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: No base64 is a bad idea as it enlarges the amount of bytes to transfer with 30%. Better just send the image as is.

Answer (score 1):

> When ever any change in image on server that time i want to make call
>   to application for new image download.

It's not possible. But you can make the date and and time of last update available (Via an API or by appending the time stamp to the image name)and check it when app starts (Or whenever you want)

Or you can use Glide or Picasso with offline capabilities enabled.